# How to enable hadoop-metrics.properties

Tags: hadoop, monitoring, metrics

I need to report hadoop metrics (such as jvm, cldb) to a text file. I modified hadoop-metrics file in a conf directory on one of the nodes to test, but output files still didn't appear.
I tried to restart YARN-nodemanager and node itself, but still no result.

Am I need to do some additional magic, like changing env variables or other configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with a wrong config. I've been using a sample config file which supposed to report Namenode and Resourcemanager metrics.
But my node didn't have both of them.
Added other metrics. Works fine.